# How do I hide the submission button basing on some conditions?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform with a mandatory Yes/No button. I want to hide the submission button if *No* is selected.

How can I set up the logical condition for achieving this?

Answer (score 5):

I just figured out that there is the 'Submit' element at the end of the webform elements under webform build tab and I can apply the conditions on that 'Submit' element.

Answer (score -2):

If I were you I'd make it easier for myself and leave it as is.

Because if the answer is no and you don't want him to submit at all so bother to make him do it from the first place!

But: if you need this to happen it is possible to have a little JavaScript doing that for you, see this [Example](https://answers.laserfiche.com/questions/49708/Can-I-hide-submit-button)